# C++: Extraction of template types

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am working on a compile-time wrapper library and stumbled upon a problem of extracting a template parameter type from a given type.

The situation is the following. I have an unchangeable class `R`:

```cpp
template <class T>
class R {};
```

I also have an unchangeable `main` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto r = new R<int>();

    // Function that knows the type of 'r'
    create_obj<decltype(r)>();

    delete r;
    return 0;
}
```

The `create_obj` function is the one that I am working on. For visualization purposes, I will write it the following way:

```cpp
template< class C >
void create_obj()
{
    // Print the type of the function (Output: R<int>*)
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<C>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

And the problem is that I need to access the `int` template parameter type of the `R` class from the `create_obj` function.

Pseudocode:

```cpp
template< 
    template < class T >
    class C<T>
>
void create_obj()
{
    // Print the type of the function (Output: int)
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to do it? I was going through the C++ documentation but I was not able to find any way to "detach" the template parameter type from the class definition.

Comment: Is `create_obj` actually supposed to take a reference to `r` or something? Currently it takes no argument and returns nothing, so it's not entirely obvious what you want it to do.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908038/4342498) what you are looking for?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have tried the `std::declval`, but the specified type `C` that is illustrated here as class `R` can be a very complicated class that cannot be easily instantiated.

Comment: @Useless That is exactly the point that there are no references, no objects, nothing can be created. The idea is just to extract a type from an already existing type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, one way to do it:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class R{};


template<typename C>
struct extract_impl{};

template<typename T>
struct extract_impl<R<T>>{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename C>
using extracted_type = typename extract_impl<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<C>>>::type;

template< class C >
void create_obj()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<extracted_type<C>,int>);
}
int main()
{
    create_obj<R<int>>();
}
```

The convention is that `R` would itself expose the type via `using`, but you wrote that it is unchangeable.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution... I have never thought of explicitly specifying class `R` in the `struct extract`. Thank you very much, I am considering it a correct solution.

Comment: @EugeneKolesnikov You are right, missed that. It also did not consider references or pointers. I edited it to be slightly cleaner. Extra `using` also removes the need for `typename`.

Answer (score 0):

I instead calling `create_obj()` through the type of `r`

```
create_obj<decltype(r)>();
```

you can call it passing directly `r`, the solution is simple

```
template <typename T>
void create_obj (R<T> const *)
 { /* do something with T */ }
```

But if you want call `create_obj()` passing only the type `R<T>` (or a type pointer to `R<T>`) without instantiating an object of type `R<T>`, you can define a lightweight type wrapper

```
template <typename>
struct typeWrapper
 { /* empty! */ };
```

redefine `create_obj()` receiving a `typeWrapper` of a `R<T>` pointer

```
template <typename T>
void create_obj (typeWrapper<R<T> *> const &)
 { /* do something with T */ }
```

and call it using `decltype(r)`

```
create_obj(typeWrapper<decltype(r)>{});
```

or directly `R<int> *`

```
create_obj(typeWrapper<R<int> *>{});
```

Another alternative is declare `create_obj` as a struct/class

```
template <typename>
struct create_obj;
```

and define only a specialization based on a `R<T> *` pointer, with a `static` `func()` method in it

```
template <typename T>
struct create_obj<R<T> *>
 {
   static void func ()
    { /* do something with T */ } 
 };
```

You can use it through `decltype(r)`

```
create_obj<decltype(r)>::func();
```

or through `R<int> *`

```
create_obj<R<int> *>::func();
```

If you prefer, instead of a `static` `func()` method, you can insert in `create_obj()` an ordinary (non `static`) method; maybe an `operator()`. But, this way, you have to instantiate a `create_obj` object to call the method.